# Why does Electron/React app freeze and without sending errors to the log?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router, electron

I have an Electron/React app with a load screen. The vast majority of the time when I make a mistake the app will send errors to Node or the console and I can debug. But with certain mistakes the app will freeze on the load screen with no logging at all. For example, if I add

```
const t = 5;
const t = 5;
```

to `src/renderer/app/actiontypes.js` I do not get the usual "Uncaught SyntaxError" message and I have to read very carefully through code to figure out what's going wrong.

Here is how the app loads:

main.js

```
app.on('ready', async () => {
    await installExtensions();
    createLoadingScreen();
    ipcMain.on('robot-load-finished', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
    ...
```

index.js

```
function run() {
    ipcRenderer.send('robot-load-finished');
    ...
loadRobotModels().then(run);
```

Does anyone why this is occurring? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by setting up a chromium remote debug configuration in Webstorm. If you have the same issue and you use Webstorm, hopefully [this tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/) will help you too.

Two other options are to use [VSCode or node-inspector](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process.md). However, node-inspector is not compatible with the latest versions of Node and the whole module seems to be abandoned due to Node's new `--inspect` flag. The electron team is planning to add support for the `--inspect` flag, here is [the ticket to watch](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6634).